# Convert column values to a list based on ID in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'value': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'group': [1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3]})
```

I want to create a new dataframe with unique IDs, but all possible (unique) values / groups added to a list, what would look like this:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'B'], 'value': [[1], [1,2]], 'group': [[1,2,3], [2,3]]})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set)

```
df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg(set)

  ID   value      group
0  A     {1}  {1, 2, 3}
1  B  {1, 2}     {2, 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'value': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'group': [1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3]})
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'B'], 'value': [[1], [1,2]], 'group': [[1,2,3], [2,3]]})


df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: x.unique().tolist())

#   ID   value      group
# 0  A     [1]  [1, 2, 3]
# 1  B  [1, 2]     [2, 3]
```